# SignalR connection negotiation fails

Tags: angular, typescript, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm trying to use SignalR in an Angular application. I'm using the Typescript client `@aspnet/signalr`.

What I get in the console is

> Information: Normalizing '/api/signalr?connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22myhub%22%7D%5D' to 'http://server:port/api/signalr?connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22myhub%22%7D%5D'.
>
> Debug: Starting HubConnection.
>
> Debug: Starting connection with transfer format 'Text'.
>
> Debug: Sending negotiation request:
>   http://server:port/api/signalr/negotiate?connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22kanbanhub%22%7D%5D
>
> Error: Failed to start the connection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

The error seems to come from the line `if (!(_i < transports_1.length)) return [3 /*break*/, 9];` in `HttpConnection`. It could be related to the fact that the negotiation response does not contain the `availableTransports` array.

```
{
    "Url":"/api/signalr",
    "ConnectionToken":"XXX",
    "ConnectionId":"XXX",
    "KeepAliveTimeout":20.0,
    "DisconnectTimeout":30.0,
    "ConnectionTimeout":110.0,
    "TryWebSockets":false,
    "ProtocolVersion":"1.2",
    "TransportConnectTimeout":5.0,
    "LongPollDelay":0.0
}
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that I'm using ASP.NET Core SignalR on client side and ASP.NET SignalR on server side, which are incompatible.

Instead of `@aspnet/signalr` I should use `signalr`.

Comment: That project was put on hold until we will upgrade to .net core, but if you're using compatible libraries on client and server it should work.